# What is the best way for connecting Django models choice fields with React js select options

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I find myself stuck in dealing with Django models choice fields and react select options. May someone kindly help. This is my models code:

```
class AccountType(models.Model):

    category = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=(
            (AccountCategories.ASSET, "Asset"),
            (AccountCategories.LIABILITY, "Liability"),
            (AccountCategories.EQUITY, "Equity"),
            (AccountCategories.REVENUE, "Revenue"),
            (AccountCategories.EXPENSE, "Operating Expense"),
        )
    )

    classification = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=(
            (AccountClassifications.NONE, ""),
            (AccountClassifications.CURRENT, "Current"),
            (AccountClassifications.NONCURRENT, "Long-Term"),
        )
    )
```

I cant seem to figure out on how to make these choices to be my select options in React form. Was thinking maybe the solution may be in validating or cleaning these choices in my serializers but I am stuck on the how especially on linking with a React Form. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I remembered Beazley's Tutorial on Python builtin SuperHeros or something like that and came up with this solution. Might not be the best as far as the DRY principle is concerned, but it works like a charm and for anyone who has struggled with the same issue and has no other way around, here is how I did it:

```
  ACCOUNT_TYPES_CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        (100, 'Do Not Choose Me'),
        (0, 'Asset'),
        (1, 'Liability'),
        (2, 'Equity'),
        (3, 'Revenue'),
        (4, 'Operating Expense')

    ]
```

I put the choices in a seperate file.

```
class AccountType(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    objects = AccountTypeManager()

    category = models.IntegerField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES_CATEGORY_CHOICES)

    classification = models.IntegerField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPES_CLASSIFICATION_CHOICES)
```

I imported the file and put it in my model and called python manage.py makemigrations

```
 class AccountingPeriodsChoicesAPIView(views.APIView):


    def get(self, request, format=None):

        my_choices = []
        choice_dict = dict(ACCOUNTING_PERIODS_CHOICES)
        for key, value in choice_dict.items():

            itered_dict = {"key": key, "value": value}
            my_choices.append(itered_dict)
        return Response(my_choices, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I created an api endpoint for it. I know that might be too much of work but it does work. Converting it into a dictionary and then unpacking it through .items(), and assigning the value and key and then returning it in Response did the trick. Calling it as an endpoint allows me to manage it under redux state and its doing what its suppose to do. Violla!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-js-choices](https://pypi.org/project/django-js-choices/)

From the docs, the usage is simple:

> Overview Django JS Choices is a small Django app that makes handling
> of model field choices in javascript easy.
>
> For example, given the model…
>
> ```
> # models.py:
>
> class Student(models.Model):
>     FRESHMAN = 'FR'
>     SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
>     JUNIOR = 'JR'
>     SENIOR = 'SR'
>     YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
>         (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
>         (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
>         (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
>         (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
>     )
>     year_in_school = models.CharField(
>         max_length=2,
>         choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
>         default=FRESHMAN,
>     )
> ```
>
> …the choices are accesible in javascript.
>
> ```
> Choices.pairs("year_in_school");
> ```
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> [
>     {value: "FR", label: "Freshman"},
>     {value: "SO", label: "Sophomore"},
>     {value: "JR", label: "Junior"},
>     {value: "SR", label: "Senior"}
> ]
> ```
>
> Display values are also accesible.
>
> ```
> Choices.display("year_in_school", "FR")
> Choices.display("year_in_school", {"year_in_school": "FR"})
> ```
>
> In both cases the result is
>
> ```
> "Freshman"
> ```

Comment: thanks lots I have been struggling a lot with this. Will look into it and will be back. I am very grateful

Comment: I did check the library it seems to be good but not compatible with django ==3.0. Thanks for your effort that means lots to me

Comment: In the requirements says it supports Django (1.5+)

Comment: It was uninstalling my django==3.0 version and I stopped it right away. But the library helped me see thngs clearly. Thanks a lot and you can always check how I solved it below

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way for me was to save the choices data in json format and convert the file in models.py.

So the choices.json file would look like that:

```
// choices.json
{
"ACCOUNT_TYPES_CATEGORY_CHOICES": [
        {"value": 100, "display": 'Do Not Choose Me'),
        {"value": 0, "display": 'Asset'),
        {"value": 1, "display": 'Liability'),
        {"value": 2, "display": 'Equity'),
        {"value": 3, "display": 'Revenue'),
        {"value": 4, "display": 'Operating Expense')
],
...
}
```

In the models.py file convert the json file to a list of dict with tuples:

```
# models.py
def json2Tuples(jsonData):
    """
    Django only takes tuples (actual value, human readable name) so we need to repack the json in a dictionay of tuples
    """
    dicOfTupple = dict()
    for key, valueList in jsonData.items():
        dicOfTupple[str(key)] = [(dic["value"], dic["display"])
                                 for dic in valueList]
    return dicOfTupple

with open('choices.json') as f:
    choices_json = json.load(f)
choices = json2Tuples(choices_json)

class AccountType(models.Model):

    category = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=choices[“ACCOUNT_TYPES_CATEGORY_CHOICES“]
    )
...
```

For React you would need to install json-loader:

```
npm install json-loader
```

And adjust your react form:

```
import React from "react";
import { Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import jsonData from import jsonData from "/choices.json";

const MyForm = ({ handleChange }) => {
  const choices = jsonData.ACCOUNT_TYPES_CATEGORY_CHOICES;
  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <h2>Account Type</h2>
      
      <Form.Group className="w-75 mt-4">
        <Form.Control
          placeholder="Account type"
          as="select"
          onChange={handleChange("account_type")}
          name="account_type"
        >
          {choices.map((c) => (
            <option key={c.value} value={c.value}>
              {c.display}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Form.Control>
      </Form.Group>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: But what if client and server do not share the same file system (e.g. they are on different machines) ?

Comment: In that case, I guess what @DUMBA suggested is more suitable. In my example, I serve React inside one of the Django templates. The advantage of my proposed solution is that you don't blow up your views file if you have a lot of choices fields.

Comment: `python manage.py makemigrations` is giving >No such file or directory